# In javascript, what does the ! sign do in front of an array bracket?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm making a vscode extension and I see this code snippet used online a  lot, but what does the ! here mean? I have never seen not used like this and don't even no what to google to find out what it means.

```
const workspaceRoot: WorkspaceFolder = workspace.workspaceFolders![0]
```